# Android simulator cant run app

Tags: java, android-studio

im making a simple app with youtube views and stuff but whenever i run the app i get no errors but the app doesn't open and on my simulator it says "CFBC (the name of my app) Has stopped running" here is my code i have 6 activities i know its a lot but if anyone can tell me why its crashing with 0 errors would help a ton

```js
package org.cfbcla.cfbc;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by kwia on 8/4/17.
 */

public class Display extends AppCompatActivity {
    YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
    Button btnPlay;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);

        mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                List<String> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
                videoList.add("QOwE0XQei_M");
                videoList.add("5sTXWESDBB0");
                youTubePlayer.loadVideos(videoList);



            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        };
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YTConfig.getApiKey(), mOnInitializedListener);

            }
        });



    }


    public void onButtonclick4(View v4) {
        if (v4.getId() == R.id.button3) {
            Intent i4 = new Intent(Display.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i4);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
package org.cfbcla.cfbc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by kwia on 8/4/17.
 */

public class Display2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display2);
    }
    public void onButtonclick4(View v4) {
        if (v4.getId() == R.id.button) {
            Intent i4 = new Intent(Display2.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i4);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
package org.cfbcla.cfbc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;


/**
 * Created by kwia on 8/4/17.
 */

public class Display3 extends AppCompatActivity{
    YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
    Button btnPlay;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display3);
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);

        mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("sFXQ1vAaKXA");



            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        };
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YTConfig.getApiKey(), mOnInitializedListener);

            }
        });



    }
    public void onButtonclick4(View v4) {
        if (v4.getId() == R.id.button) {
            Intent i4 = new Intent(Display3.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i4);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
package org.cfbcla.cfbc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by kwia on 8/4/17.
 */

public class Display4 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display4);
    }
    public void onButtonclick4(View v4) {
        if (v4.getId() == R.id.button4) {
            Intent i4 = new Intent(Display4.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i4);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
package org.cfbcla.cfbc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.A) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }

    public void onButtonClick2(View v2) {
        if (v2.getId() == R.id.C) {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display2.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
    }
    public void onbuttonClick3(View v3) {
        if (v3.getId() == R.id.S) {
            Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display3.class);
            startActivity(i3);
        }
    }
    public void onButtonclick4(View v4) {
        if (v4.getId() == R.id.M) {
            Intent i4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display4.class);
            startActivity(i4);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: what should i put i have no idea where the problem is @JoeC

Comment: Have you tried running the app on an actual android device? Also, you say no errors, but are you in debug and have you checked the logcat for errors?

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder how do i do any of that and

Comment: If you have an actual android device, you can just use a usb cable to plug into your PC and when you run in debug mode it will be one of the devices shown on list of potential devices to run yuour code on. Helpfuil advice here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: Getting to your logcat error messages in Android Studio is explained here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html. It is vital you learn how to use logcat else you will never debug runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder!! ill look into those that should help a lot

Comment: You are welcome. The logcat can be a bit confusing at first, a couple of tips. 1. Take off verbose mode, too much info, use drop down to chose errors. 2. After a crash look for the part of the logcat report that starts Caused by: - this will be where things went wrong.

Comment: Then if you know the Caused by, you will probably be able to isolate a smaller section of code. If you cannot work out why, you are in a better position to post a more focused question that SO colleagues can answer. Post the code causing the error and the Caused by: part of the logcat.

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder so for the display 3 it made an android:id and a normal id which should i delete

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: @BusinessPlanQuickBuilder i accidentally made a view with no properties in one of my activities its working now...

Comment: Fantastic, well debugged